# Adaptive payment with Recurring in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

I need to use adaptive payment with Recursion in Paypal. Paypal has option to use Adaptive payment and Recursive payment separately, but I need to use both in single transaction. I tried to find out but I am not getting the solution, some answers says that its not possible to use both in single transaction but I dont have any specification in Paypal web site for this. So please advice me for this and if it is not possible then please give me some authenticated web link for this

Comment: What have you tried? provide code maybe? or do you expect us to do everything for you?

Comment: @Hallur, thanks for your comment, how can I provide source code ? I have done the adaptive payment and I also have the idea of recurring but no idea to combine these two. However here is the link which I am using : https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php

Comment: This site is not a search engine... if you need advice, then use google or read the manuals for the things you're working with. This site is about programming issues, not recommending books or links....

Comment: I know that this is not a search engine, and also I tried to find out some solution but somehow I am not able to and thats why I raised a question here. This question has 100% programming issue and I have mentioned link in terms of reference of some solution and if it is not possible then I asked for link. Anyway thanks for your help